# Evitar refresco de página al enviar formulario

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario en el que el botón submit lanza una función de Javascript. 
Esta función lo que hace es una llamada a AJAX y en esta llamada ya accedo a ficheros python que se encargan de darme datos.

El problema lo tengo en que cuando me llegan los datos de la petición, la página hace como un refresco y se me ponen los datos por defecto en el formulario, decir que estos datos por defecto los cojo con otra petición AJAX de una BD cuando se refresca la página.

Este es el **form**:

```
<form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="enabled">Habilitado:</label>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: center">
                <input type="radio" name="enabled" id="enabledY" value="true"/><label class="radio-inline">Si</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: center">
                <input type="radio" name="enabled" id="enabledN" value="false"/><label class="radio-inline">No</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <label for="host">Host:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="host" placeholder="Ej: localhost">
        <br/>
        <label for="port">Puerto:</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="port" placeholder="Ej: 5000">
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 0px">
            <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Guardar" id="guardar">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center">
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" value="Borrar">
            </div>
        </div>    
    </form>
```

Y este el código **JS**:

```
$("#guardar").on("click",function(){
            var habilitado;
            if(document.getElementById("enabledY").checked == true){
                habilitado = true;
            }else{
                if(document.getElementById("enabledN").checked == true){
                    habilitado = false;
                }else{
                    alert("Debe seleccionar una opción de habilitación");
                    return;
                }
            }
            var host;
            if ($("#host").val() != ""){
                host = $("#host").val();
            }else{
                alert("El campo del host no puede estar vacío");
                return;
            }
            var puerto;
            if($("#port").val() != ""){
                puerto = $("#port").val();
            }else{
                alert("El campo de puerto no puede estar vacío");
                return;
            }
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/views/saveProbeConf/',
                data: {
                    'sonda' : $("#selector").val(),
                    'habilitado' : habilitado,
                    'host' : host,
                    'puerto' : puerto
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    $.each(response,function(i,item){
                        if(i == 'habilitado'){
                            if(item){
                                $("#enabledY").prop("checked", true).button("refresh");
                                $("#enabledY").val("true");
                            }else{
                                $("#enabledN").prop("checked", true).button("refresh");
                                $("#enabledN").val("false");
                            }
                        }else{
                            if(i == 'host'){
                                $("#host").val(item.toString());
                            }else{
                                if(i == 'puerto'){
                                    $("#port").val(item.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }); 
        });
```

Comment: Si estás usando AJAX no tendría que recargarse la página, pero sin ver el código no te podemos decir más.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código HTML de tu formulario y el Javascript para poder reproducir tu problema y ayudarte a solucionarlo? Existen múltiples formas de realizar la cancelación del envío de un formulario, pero sin ver tu código no podemos proponerte una.

Comment: Ahí está el código y gracias @AMB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te falta parar la accion estandar de envio de formulario. Cambia tu JS por

```
$("#guardar").on("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // resto de tu codigo
 });
```

Comment: Joe que descuido madre mia, pensé que lo había metido, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Quita el method="post" del formulario y el type="submit" del botón de guardar, este código hace que se recargue el formulario. Además no lo necesitas porque estás haciendo el post con jquery

Answer (score 0):

Ene esta linea, donde defines el botón de envío cambiale el `type="submit"` por `type="button"` quedando de esta manera:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Guardar" id="guardar">
```

Con esto lograrás que sea un simple botón ya que cuando es de `type="submit"` internamente haces que caiga en el la responsabilidad de hacer el `Post` o `Get` del fromulario.

Answer (score 0):

te dejo la respuesta que me dierona  mi. Con un ejemplo básico.

Si dejas el botón fuera del formulario no lo enviara, entonces validas los campos ( yo no he hecho ninguna validacion), si la variable valido es correcta enviara el formulario con submit() de javascript en caso contrario muestra una alerta para que valides los campos. Prueba cambiando la variable de false a true para ver como te funciona.

```js
function sendForm() {
  var valido = false; //DEBERIAS REALIZAR LAS VALIDACIONES
  alert("ENTRO SEND");
  alert("valido: " + valido);
  if (valido) {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
  } else {
    alert("VALIDA LOS CAMPOS");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="pagina.php" method="post">
  <p>
    <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
    <input type="text" id="nombre"><br/>
    <label for="apellido">Apellido: </label>
    <INPUT type="text" id="apellido"><br/>
    <label for="email">Rut: </label>
    <INPUT type="text" id="email"><br/>

  </p>
</form>
<button onclick="javascript:sendForm();" class="btn btn-second" title="Continuar">Boton</button>
```

Comment: Como marcaron mi pregunta como duplicado, la dejo acá para que no se pierda el material.